# unable to set select value options

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript, ajax, jquery

Helloo..
I am stucked in a very difficult situation.
I am implementing ajax in magento, but it is not working.
Whenever I use that code in home page it run properly but the html is not added to the select box.Same is if run in another page, run properly
    I knw there are some issues in my home page
    But I am unable to get those, as there are no errors in console 
    Please guide or suggest me something
 This is my ajax code

```
function getMake(country)
    {
        jQuery(".spinner").css("display", "block");
       var strUser = country;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            url: "productlist/index/getMake/", 
            data: {
                country: strUser},
            success: function(data)
            {
                jQuery(".spinner").css("display", "none");
                 jQuery("#selectbox1" ).html( data );
                //document.getElementById("selectbox1").innerHTML = data;
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

I had even used js / jquery but nothing is working.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very common error is to find duplicates ids in the DOM maybe you have 2 selectbox1 elements in the home page, so try to execute `jQuery("#selectbox1")` in your browser console and check if you have more than 1 objects match.

Check if your js block is executed and also check if XHR response is OK, ie:

```
...
success: function(data)
{
     ...
     console.log(data);
     ...
}
...
```

Comment: Thanx for the response 
Console show my data, actually data is fetching but the thing is it is not added to selec box.I also checked jQuery("#selectbox1") and it replies a single element

Comment: Ok so try to replace: `jQuery("#selectbox1").html(data)` for: `jQuery("#selectbox1").empty().append(data);`-- (i always preffer this approach because i'm just a little paranoid --

Comment: Boy I just say I love you

Comment: oh one more thing, are you executing this code after the DOM is ready?

Comment: You make my day I was suffering from this from last 5 days and now I resolved it it was because of two same id only
I now changed all the ids related to it and now it is working fine
Thanx a ton mann

Comment: cool! is a common issue i tend to use long and semantic ids for that.. and because  i'm a paranoid! as say before:)